# What is the default color of the dialog background fill?

Tags: android, android-layout

When Android `AlertDialog` shows, the background around this dialog becomes darker. This is probably achieved by first filling the whole screen with a half-transparent color and then putting a dialog on top of that.

My question is: what is the default color of that background fill?

```
#88666666 //looks close, but not enough
```

Comment: Change your application theme suitable to dialogues..

Comment: It might not be exactly the same, but the default scrim color of DrawerLayout is #99000000. You can find it in androidx DrawerLayout class where it has:
private static final int DEFAULT_SCRIM_COLOR = 0x99000000;

Answer (score 15):

**For future readers:**

What question author calls dialog background fill is called **Scrim** in Material Design spec.

So the scrim color according to [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#theming) is

> Color : #000000
>
> Opacity : 32%

```
    <color name="background">#52000000</color>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check the AppCompat's Dialog I believe it is using:

```
<color name="dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark">#80bebebe</color>
<color name="dim_foreground_disabled_material_light">#80323232</color>
```

However on my own testing I think it's `#99000000` (black at 62 % opacity)

Answer (score 0):

Try it!. **It worked very good!**

in **onCreate()**

```
final int baseAlpha = (0x99000000) >>> 24;
layout.setBackgroundColor(baseAlpha);
```

in **manifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.web.WebPopupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.TransparentWebPopup" />
```

in **style.xml**

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TransparentWebPopup" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_trans</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

</style>
```

in **color.xml**

```
 <color name="color_trans">#99000000</color>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this color code #80000000@activity